# Java duda metodo next()

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un programa con una base de datos, específicamente con MySql.
Necesitaría saber que función cumple el método next() dentro del bucle porque es lo único que no entiendo del código.

```
private void button_okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    usuario = txt_usuario.getText();
    contraseña = txt_pass.getText();

    try {

        Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/servicio_tecnico", "root", "");
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT username,password FROM usuarios");
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
                usuarioCorrecto = rs.getString(1);
                contraseñaCorrecta = rs.getString(2);
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, contraseñaCorrecta);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error " + e);
    }

}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next() Hay algo que no allas entendido de la documentacion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que ver las consultas como una tabla. `next()` te hace avanzar a traves de las filas y el metodo `getString(No. columna)` a traves de las columnas.

```
          getString(1)  getString(2)
         +------------+------------+
         | columna 1  | columna 2  |
+--------+------------+------------+
| fila 1 | username 1 | password 1 | next()
+--------+------------+------------+   |
| fila 2 | username 2 | password 2 | next()
+--------+------------+------------+   |
| fila 3 | username 3 | password 3 | next()
+--------+------------+------------+   |
                                       v
```

Comment: Ahhh, tiene lógica. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Cuando haces un consulta el resultado queda en un Result set, el next() lo que hace es recorrer el objeto una linea ejemplo  en tu consultas hace un SELECT si el la contraseña tiene éxito retornara algo como :

```
         |username |password|
         |------------------|
         |usuario1 |12345   | <---Next te leerá esta linea y si hubiera mas seguiría leyendo por el While cuando ya no hay linea se detiene y sale del ciclo
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!